# Rails dynamically add condition to mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

How to add condition dynamically to sql query

for example if i have one element than it will look like

```
query=['one_element']

User.where('name LIKE ?, %"#{query[0]}"%')
```

but if it more than one

```
User.where('name LIKE ? and LIKE ? and Like... , %"#{query}"%', ..so on)
```

Im use `myslq`

so my main goal to split search query if it contains more than 2 words and search by them separately in one sql query

```
not where(name:'john dou') but where(name:'john' and name:'dou')
```

Comment: Both responders below have answered giving you a way to generate SQL with "OR" combining the conditions.  But your example above uses "AND" to combine the conditions.  Just to confirm before I answer:   do you really want the "AND" operator used here?  For example would you want "WHERE name LIKE '%erky%' AND name LIKE '%eef%'" to match a record with name = "beef jerky", but not match record with name = "beef" or name = "jerky"?

Answer (score 0):

First split the word by it's separator like this `query.split(' ')` this will give you array of words.  Then you can use like below in rails.

`User.where(name:  ['John', 'dou']`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version of MySQL that supports `RLIKE` or `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
User.where("RLIKE(name, :name_query)", name_query: query.join("|"))
```

Otherwise, you'll have to manually build with the ActiveRecord `or` operator:

```
# In the User model
scope :name_like, ->(name_part) {
  return self.all if name_part.blank?
  where("name LIKE :name_query", name_query: "%#{name_part}%")
}
scope :names_like, ->(names) {
  relation = User.name_like(names.shift)
  names.each { |name| relation = relation.or(name_like(name)) }
  relation
}
```

Then you can pass it an array of any name partials you want:

```
query = ["john", "dou"]
User.names_like(query)
```